# We have an ISBN: $\left(\sum_{k=1}^{9}(11-k) \cdot x_{k}+p\right) \text{ mod } 11=0$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, summation, divisibility

> $x_{1},...,x_{9} \in \left\{0,1,...,9\right\}$ are the first nine
>   places of an ISBN and $p$ is the check digit, given by these digits
>   which fulfills the condition:
>
> $\left(\sum_{k=1}^{9}(11-k) \cdot x_{k}+p\right) \text{ mod } 11=0$
>
> Say how it's possible to realize the following error by the deviation
>   of the check digit: The change of one of the nine digits to any other
>   digit without changing the remaining $8$ digits (single mistake).

This is a task of an exam from 2015 and I'd like to know how it could be solved?

The first line seems a bit confusing to me because it's saying $x_{1},...$ and after we see that $0$ is included, so why there is no $x_{0}$? But the sam starts at $1$ so I conclude that there is no $x_{0}$ And how is the check digit made up of these 0-9 digits? Is it ONE of these digits or I understand it wrong? Cannot do the task because cannot understand it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x_1,\ldots x_9$ are the nine positions of the ISBM, the index (subscript) refers to the position, not its value.  Each of these is a variable, which assumes any of ten possible values.  For example $220056789$ corresponds to $x_1=2, x_2=2, x_3=0, \ldots$.

If we replace one digit (say, $x_1$ by $x_1'$), then the sum will change by subtracting $(11-1)\cdot x_1$, and adding $(11-1)\cdot x_1'$.  Hence the sum will change by $(11-1)(x_1'-x_1)$.  Note that $11-1$ is nonzero, and $x_1'-x_1$ is nonzero.  Hence their product is nonzero mod $11$.  Thus the sum will change by a nonzero number.  This is how we detect the error; the sum is no longer zero mod $11$.

Comment: Thanks so much, awesome described! :)